# DevExpress - Set Cell Value - An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

i have this code (gridview, cellvaluechanged event):

```
      private void gv1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
string value1 = Convert.ToString(gv1.GetRowCellValue(gv1.FocusedRowHandle, "unitvalue"));
object cellValue = Convert.ToUInt32(value1) * Convert.ToInt32(days_worked);
 gv1.SetRowCellValue(gv1.FocusedRowHandle, "totalvalue", cellValue);
}
```

"days_worked" is a value obtain from label control, the value of the cell does not change,
appears the following error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

"totalvalue" is a column of my database

Please help, thanks!

Comment: i think `SetRowCellValue` inside raise event `CellValueChanged`, so you need or another event, or use another function for setting value

Comment: do not know this, 3 days with the same, OMG

Comment: you use winforms? webforms?

Comment: try see [sample from documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CellValueChangedtopic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As say in documentation

> The CellValueChanged event fires in response to a cell's value being changed. The list below gives the possible reasons for this event being raised:
>
> - An end-user has closed an in-place editor after changing the editor's
>   value.
> - A cell's value has been changed using the methods provided by
>   Views. For instance, the SetRowCellValue method can be used for this
>   purpose.

So you need change your code as suggest docs

```
private void gv1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Caption != "totalvalue") return; // if event in fire from cells in column "totalvalue"

    string value1 = Convert.ToString(gv1.GetRowCellValue(gv1.FocusedRowHandle, "unitvalue"));
    object cellValue = Convert.ToUInt32(value1) * Convert.ToInt32(days_worked);
    gv1.SetRowCellValue(gv1.FocusedRowHandle, "totalvalue", cellValue);
}
```

Comment: +1 - The reason for the stackoverflow is that in the `CellValueChanged` event you set a cell value - this fires the event again - and so it goes into a "loop" until you get your exception.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH GUY, U SAVED MY LIFE, THANKS FOR HELPING TO THE COMMUNITY